# Edit bean after creation, for class I can't modify the source of?

Tags: java, spring, initialization, spring-bean

I have a spring bean which I need to change after it's created, but I don't have access to edit the source of the bean's class; so I can't use...

- init-method
- InitializingBean
- @PostConstruct

Is there some way I can detect when this bean is created by id in another class, then apply the change I need?

Thanks

Comment: Normally the only Spring beans that you didn't code, is the beans provided by the spring framework. Where does the beens that you want to change come from, and how are they instantiated ?

Comment: Our software uses a 3 tiered type of structure: platform, solution, and implementation.  The bean I'm trying to change exists in a platform library, and I'm working at the implementation level.

Comment: I hope you can hear the problem with the following "I'm trying to change an existing *platform* library". We have all tried to work around limitations, and were not able to wait for the next platform release, but extending the platform seems like the correct thing to do. If your implementation is loading all spring contexts, you can use the ```BeanPostProcessor``` as suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) to apply your own custom logic.

Example:

```
public class UserPassAuthFilterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private String usernameParameter;
    private String passwordParameter;

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) {
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) bean; 
            filter.setUsernameParameter(getUsernameParameter());
            filter.setPasswordParameter(getPasswordParameter());
        }

        return bean;
    }
    //...
}
```